# Linux xdotool symbols

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, xdotool

I'm looking to simulate the keyboard using xdotool and i'm having issues with a part of URL. The section I'm looking to type is "-episode-".

As a solution, I have a text file (hyphen.txt) that contains:

```
-
```

then I run:

```
xdotool key --file ./hyphen.txt
```

I'd like to avoid using an extra text file. Is there a way to use:

```
xdotool key <>
xdotool type <>
```

to output a hyphen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that:

```
xdotool type -
```

will produce the desired result

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
xdotool key minus
```

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
xdotool key hyphen
```

types `-`.

```
xdotool key hyphen e p i s o d e hyphen
```

types `-­episode­-`.